# MAVEN installation with JDK-1.8

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven-3

I using `aws` instance to run my `java` application and using java-1.8.0.
Have decided to install `maven` to manage the build, installed and been using to compile and build on my windows machine. Installed maven on aws using following commands:

```
sudo wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo yum install -y apache-maven
mvn --version
```

The problem with these commands is, its installing `java-1.7.0(jdk)` as a dependency. There are compile issues, while i'm using `java-1.8.0` for development.

Also tried downloading the maven.tar.gz to untar and set maven path. The error is

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I understand the problem. But from the java install, couldn't find `jdk` in /usr/lib/. Could only see `jre` folders. I could not risk java installation due to the cluster setup may get upset.

Any suggestions to help install `maven` with `java-1.8.0` dependency. thanks

Comment: As error says, you should install JDK not JRE. Please, show which commands you used to install java.

Comment: @Shirkam used sudo yum install java-1.8.0, followed by sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac

Comment: That only installs JRE. You must specify that you are installing JDK as `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` on CentOS and RedHat (as you are using yum, I suposse you're using one of those).

Comment: yes, i'm using RedHat. The problem is even after trying this: sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel. There's no jdk folder found in /user/lib/. On trying  sudo update-alternatives --config java, could see only /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java.

Comment: As i have told in the question, I cannot risk uninstalling now. But could change path of JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Try to run `javac` in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/`. If that works, change `JAVA_HOME` to that folder. If it doesn't, you should search somewhere else the folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149441/discussion-between-shirkam-and-srikanth).